# Can't stub with Kafka producer record in Spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka, spock

I'm trying to unit test some Kafka code with Spock and I'm having trouble stubbing the response to the `KafkaProducer.send()` function. Here's the line of Java code I need to get around:

```
Object out = producer.send(record).get()
```

Here's my Spock code:

```
given:
Object obj = new Object()
KafkaProducer producer = kafkaProducerService.getProducer()

when:
kafkaProducerService.publish(someData)

then:
1 * producer.send(_ as ProducerRecord).get >> obj
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '_' with class 'org.spockframework.lang.Wildcard' to class 'org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord(org.spockframework.lang.SpreadWildcard)
```

I've even tried the full wildcard route with `producer.send(_).get() >> obj` and that also doesn't work (with a wildly frustrating suggestion to use `ProducerRecord`):

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send() is applicable for argument types: (org.spockframework.lang.Wildcard) values: [[*_]]
Possible solutions: send(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord), send(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord, org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), any(), sleep(long)
```

`ProducerRecord` isn't abstract, isn't an interface, and definitely has a constructor, so what gives?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with your verification and the fact that you chained two method calls (`.send().get()`). Therefore spock will not run verification on `send` but on `get` and does not recognize the wildcard syntax. You probably need this:

```
given:
def sendResult = Mock(Future)
...

then:
1 * producer.send(_ as ProducerRecord) >> sendResult
1 * sendResult.get() >> obj
```